# is it possible to make a s:rect clickable in Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

using flex, is it possible to make a square, drawn using  s:rect , clickable?

I am trying to draw a series of coloured boxes and allow them to be clicked on to perform an action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to target it directly so I wrapped it in a BorderContainer and that did the trick. Or you could just use a BorderContainer if all you want is a box you can color and target.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="init()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            public function init():void{

                myBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, changeColor);

            }

            public function changeColor(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                myFill.color = 0xFFFF00;
            }


        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>

    </s:states>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <s:SolidColor id="myFill" color="0xFF0000" />
        <s:SolidColorStroke id="myStroke" color="0x000000" weight="2" />
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:BorderContainer id="myBox" >     
        <s:Rect width="200" height="200" fill="{myFill}" stroke="{myStroke}" id="box1" />
    </s:BorderContainer>



</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have this working on is own, but when i put it into my app it no longer works properly. 

I am using <mx:TabNavigator x="23" y="25" width="922" height="565" id="tab">
  <s:NavigatorContent width="100%" height="100%" label="Home" >

and wrapping the box inside of that. the box is in my second tab and wondered if that was affecting the way the listener worked?